# HTML restructure for Navbar issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make the children not effect the navbar and display exactly like a dropdown menu.

Current example at:
dev4you.byethost15.com

Function should be as follows:

1. User Hovers over Parent Item
2. Children are shown in a box like list, Underneath.

Currently what is happening is when the children are displayed on parent hover then the navbar is pushed down to compensate, i do not want that functionality, i am trying to create a dropdown menu here.

Also other html structure advice is appreciated if this one is not optimal.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header col-md-8">
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home">Portal</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="item in data">
          <li class="innerLi"><a ng-mouseover="isChildrenVisible=true" ng-mouseleave= "isChildrenVisible=false">{{item.title}}</a></li>
          <ul style="padding-left:20px;">
            <li class="menuchild" ng-show="isChildrenVisible" ng-repeat="child in item.children ">
                    <p>{{child.title}}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: And which part of all that is that's not working for you?

Comment: @Christina I believe HTML/CSS issue? Basically Position of how Children are Displayed.

Comment: created a fiddle and everything working as expected. what is the issue?
http://jsfiddle.net/cxv674k7/

Comment: If it's a matter of positioning you should also give as your CSS as well as a few more details on what is wrong with the current position. Perhaps you could put everything in a plunkr / jsfiddle?

Comment: @Christina Ill build a plunkr

Comment: @Christina had trouble with the plunkr thing so i just uploaded the site to my server so you can have a check.

http://dev4you.byethost15.com/#/

You can see the children are pushing down the navbar i would like to have it so the children are flowing over the navbar just like a dropdown element would.

Answer (score 0):

Use these css settings in your inner children `li`.

```
<li ng-show="isChildrenVisible" ng-repeat="child in item.children " class="ng-scope ng-hide innerLi" 
">
 <p class="ng-binding">Long Sub2</p></li>
```

CSS:

```
  .innerLi{
      position: absolute;
      top: 65%;
      margin-left: -25px;
    }
```